# Image lays on top of link, but I need my link to be clickable

Tags: html, css

I have a Logo at the top of my page that is designed that it has letters that hang down over the menu bar(a 'y').
With no real special coding (just setting the heights of the containers I have gotten this to look fine.
My problem is that the img blocks the links in the menu from being clickable as the links are sitting behind the transparent background of the logo.

I hope that made sense.
I will include my code, but as I said its pretty simple.

```
<header>
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="/media/1001/logo.png"  />
</header>
<menu>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">How To Order</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li class="noBorder"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   </ul>
</menu>
```

CSS:

```
header { background-color: #3a8c86; border-bottom: solid 4px #20716b; height: 52px; }
  header img.logo {margin-left:5px;}
menu { background-color: #e78898; height: 21px; }
  menu ul li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 3px 0 0 14px; padding-right: 14px; border-right: solid 1px white; }
     menu ul li a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: am kinda lost with what u exactly want ,but i think u may looking for `z-index` so on the div u want it to be on top add this to it `position: relative; z-index: 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Position the image and then give it a lower `z-index` value

```
header img.logo {
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ydvmedr/

Comment: This does not work as I said I need the image to be on top so that the "y" hanging down shows up on top of the menu. But the rest of the bottom section of the image is fully transparent and that's where I should see the menu links and be able to click on them.

Comment: @Yoni what do you mean by "y"

Comment: My logo is textual and has the letter "y" which hangs lower than the rest of the word. My designer would like to see that "y"  lay on top of the menu.

Comment: I have updated and here is also a link to my page..
http://buybirthcontrol.co.yonas.arvixevps.com/default2.aspx